# Add a button to UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

How can I add a button to a UIPickerView?
Thanks.

The result should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way. You can just put a button on top of it. I'm guessing that button was just well-designed to look right in that position :)