# How do you add a button to a UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uipickerview

How do you add a single button to UIPickerView that can be used to dismiss or hide the PickerView?

I found a few solutions to these problems and many did not seem to come up with the answer I wanted. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211996/add-a-button-to-uipickerview) question was the closest I could find to what I was asking, but it is very outdated so I wanted to display my solution. I have a subclass of UIPickerView that I wanted to add a UIButton to be able to dismiss on. I *do not* want a UIPickerView with a UIToolBar inside.

The below image describes exactly what I am looking for where the done button is added to my subclass of UIPickerView

[image]

It may seem trivial that all you need to do is add a UIButton to the UIPickerView and add a target to call on a method, because I also want the PickerView to respond to user selection on the rows, pressing the Done button caused no response

Comment: You have not explained what dismiss means. How does the picker appear in the first place? As a keyboard at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create subclass of UIView as such

```
class CustomViewWithPicker: UIView {
    
    let picker = UIPickerView(frame: .zero)
    let pickerTitle = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
    
    let title: String = "Picker Title"
    let buttonName: String = "Button"
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        didLoad()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        didLoad()
    }
    
    func didLoad() {
        
        self.addSubview(picker)
        self.addSubview(pickerTitle)
        self.addSubview(button)
        
        picker.backgroundColor = .tertiarySystemBackground
        picker.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        picker.frame = .zero
        
        pickerTitle.text = title
        pickerTitle.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22)
        pickerTitle.textAlignment = .center
        pickerTitle.backgroundColor = .tertiarySystemBackground
        
        button.setTitle(buttonName, for: .normal)
        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right
        button.contentVerticalAlignment = .top
        button.isSelected = true
        
        self.updateConstraints()
    }
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if self.point(inside: point, with: event) {
            return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        }
        guard isUserInteractionEnabled, !isHidden, alpha > 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        
        for subview in subviews.reversed() {
            let convertedPoint = subview.convert(point, from: self)
            if let hitView = subview.hitTest(convertedPoint, with: event) {
                return hitView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
    
    override func updateConstraints() {
        // Make Constraints ...
    }
}
```

In the ViewController conform to UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    let customView = CustomViewWithPicker()
    let labels = ["label0", "label1", "label2", "label3", "label4", "label5"]
    var selectedRow = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        customView.picker.delegate = self
        customView.picker.dataSource = self

        customView.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doneButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        self.view.addSubview(customView)
        
    }
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return labels.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return labels[row]
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectedRow = row
    }
    
    @objc func doneButtonTapped(_ selectedButton: UIButton) {
        if selectedButton.isSelected {
            print("Done Button Tapped")
        }
    }
}
```

I looked far and wide for a UIPickerView implementation that did not rely on UIToolBar to detect a tap on the button to no avail.

Thank you to Duncan C. for the input and advice

Comment: Apple generally says not to muck with their component's view hierarchy. Adding subviews to a subclass of UIPickerView is fragile, and not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Don't do that.

Apple says not to mess with their components' view hierarchy. You should create a component that includes a picker and your button, and make them look like a single, multi-part component. That way if Apple changes the internal structure of UIPickerView in future releases it won't break you.

Comment: So, this multi-part component would be a subclass of UIView then? Would you happen to have a link to Apple documentation that perhaps explains a better way of subclassing UIKit elements?

Comment: I tried to find where in Apple's docs it says not to mess with the view hierarchy of its specialized UIView components (like picker view, table view, collection view, slider, etc.) But couldn't find it. If you create a composite view that contains a picker and other views you probably would not need to subclass UIPickerView.

Comment: I see, so subclassing UIView with UILabel, UIPickerView, and UIButton properties is perhaps the best practice?

Comment: That would be my advice, yes. If you subclass UIPickerView and add subviews to it, then at some future date Apple changes the geometry or behavior of the base class, they can break you. (The basic guidance is to only depend on the documented public interface for framework classes. If you depend on they way something is currently implemented internally that's not part of the public contract, you become dependent on that internal implementation, and fragile.)